# Connecting Tables with No Key

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation where I want to connect two tables that do not have a key to link them within Oracle 8i. I have Table A with some information and a datetime and Table B with some information and a datetime. What I would like is everything from Table A with the corresponding data from Table B for the time in Table A I'll mock it up below:

```
Table A                     |   Table B
John   31/07/2012 10:50:32  |   Travel to Library   31/07/2012 10:48:23
John   31/07/2012 10:55:49  |   Arrive at Library   31/07/2012 11:02:34
John   31/07/2012 11:00:15  |   Reading Book        31/07/2012 11:07:11
John   31/07/2012 11:05:23  |
John   31/07/2012 11:10:12  |
```

What I want to create is this:

```
John   31/07/2012 10:50:32   Travel to Library   
John   31/07/2012 10:55:49   Travel to Library       
John   31/07/2012 11:00:15   Travel to Library            
John   31/07/2012 11:05:23   Arrive at Library
John   31/07/2012 11:10:12   Reading Book
```

As might be suspected this is in relation to a table that contains GPS data that I receive every 5 minutes and another table completely unrelated that lists activities. My closest attempt so far has been to write a query in two parts the first part is looking at the activity and returning an activity date and a next activity date then connecting the two tables based on the name of the person involved and returning the GPS data when it is between the two activity dates, I've also done it the opposite way around with GPS date and Next GPS date and returning the activity if it is between those. Neither way is returning all of either set of data.

I feel that my major malfunction lies in my use of the leap/lag functions to get a before or after datetime. Perhaps I'm just overlooking the obvious answer.

I could really use some help to point me in the right direction with this.

Comment: my thought was a LAG function also.  can you post what you tried?

Comment: what if we have `Steve 31/07/2012 11:00:15` (another person at the same time) in table A and `Arrive at Library   31/07/2012 11:03:34` two different arrivals(1 minute between).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select Name, Time, Activity from
(
    select
        a.Name, a.Time, b.Activity,
        row_number() over (partition by a.Time order by b.time desc) as rn
    from TableA a, TableB b
    where a.time >= b.time and a.Name = b.Name
)
where rn = 1;
```

Note: I assumed that the GPS data also comes with a name in the table.

Comment: The OP states they're on 8i. Support for the ANSI join syntax was only introduced in 9i.

Comment: @APC: Thanks for the info. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, You guessed right in that there was a connection to be made through name. This SQL seemed to work just fine. There was a big performance hit and I had to limit it to the last two days worth of data so that it runs (now at a minuscule 6 minutes and 54 seconds), but it returns the right data. Thank you again.

Comment: If performance is an issue you should try the LEAD() option,  adjusted for whatever further joins and partitioning you require.  It may well be more efficient with large numbers of recods.  Of course, guessing is always a bad way to approach tuning.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 8i which is *really old*.  However, provided you are using 8.1.6 or higher, you can get your desired result with the LEAD() analytic function.  You didn't provide actual table structures so I mocked them up like this:

```
create table A (name varchar2(10), dt date);           
create table B (event varchar2(20), dt date);
```

Gven those column tables this query will work:

```
select a.name, a.dt, b.event
from a 
     , ( select b.* 
         , lead (b.dt, 1, null) over
              (order by dt asc) as next_dt
        from b ) b
where a.dt >= b.dt
and ( a.dt < b.next_dt or b.next_dt is null)
```

[The SQL Fiddle uses 11gR2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fef6/6) but this syntax should still work on 8i.

NB: analytic functions where only licensed with Enterprise Edition until a point release of 9iR1 (9.0.1.3 or some such) if you're bothered by such niceties.

Comment: As to the Oracle 8i it's a bit complicated, and paraphrasing from our French IT team (having a French IT team could be the basis for the problem), he database is Oracle 11g Enterprise, however the database lives in France (I'm in the UK) and connect to it via a Citrix network. I use AquaData to run SQL commands to the database and it is AquaData that is limiting my commands to only those used for Oracle 8i. The basic answer I have received is that when a few ongoing projects are completed later this year, then we will upgrade AquaData and my quest for old Oracle SQL commands will be over.

Comment: As to the SQL itself this is vaguely what I was attempting on my own. It seems to limit the returned values to Activities that happen between GPS points, with corresponding GPS data. What I was looking for was all GPS points with corresponding last action. The second answer achieved this. I do like the fact that I did seem to be thinking along the right lines though, just didn't get to the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems a bit harsh to mark me down for providing a solution which matches the exact data and output you posted.